# Determine whether the given set as follows is a vector space or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Determine whether the set $V=\Bbb R^2$ with vector addition and scalar multiplication defined as:
$(x,y)+(x_1,y_1)=(x+x_1,y+y_1+1)$ and
$r \cdot (x,y) = (rx,ry+r-1)$ for all $(x,y),(x_1,y_1) \in V$ and for all $r \in \Bbb R$
is a vector space or not.

**Attempt:**
Let $(x,y),(x_1,y_1),(a,b),(c,d),(e,f) \in V$ and $r \in \Bbb R$. Then,

1. $(x,y)+(x_1,y_1) \in V$ (by definition of $+$).
2. $r\cdot (x,y) \in V$ (by definition of $\cdot$).
3. Since
   \begin{equation*}
   (0,-1) + (x,y) = (0+x,-1+y+1) = (x,y),
   \end{equation*}
   then $(0,-1)$ is the additive identity in $V$.
4. Since
   \begin{equation*}
   (-x,-y-2) + (x,y) = (-x+x,-y-2+y+1) = (0,-1),
   \end{equation*}
   then $(-x,-y-2)$ is the additive invers in $V$.
5. $(a,b)+((c,d)+(e,f)) = ((a,b)+(c,d))+(e,f)$.
6. $r \cdot ((a,b)+(c,d)) = r\cdot (a,b) + r \cdot (c,d)$.
7. $(r+s)\cdot (a,b) = r \cdot (a,b) + s \cdot (a,b)$.
8. $1 \cdot (a,b) = (a,b)$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity in $\Bbb R$.
9. $(rs)\cdot (a,b) = r\cdot (s \cdot (a,b))$.
10. $(a,b)+(c,d)=(c,d)+(a,b)$.

Hence, $V$ is a vector space under $+$ and $\cdot$ defined as above.

Am I true?

Comment: IMO, you are correct since they all are the vector space criteria of a set.

Comment: Great! Thanks Sir.

Comment: Notice that I comment as above with assuming that you have shown the other 6 properties, that is, the axiom 5,6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my prove of the other 6 axioms above (axiom 5,6,7,8,9,10).

For 5:
\begin{align*}
(a,b)+((c,d)+(e,f)) &= (a,b)+(c+e,d+f+1) \\
&= (a+(c+e),b+(d+f+1)+1) \\
&= ((a+c)+e,f+(b+d+1)+1) \\
&= (a+c,b+d+1)+(e,f) \\
&= ((a,b)+(c,d))+(e,f).
\end{align*}

For 6:
\begin{align*}
r \cdot ((a,b)+(c,d)) &=
r \cdot (a+c,b+d+1) \\
&= (r(a+c),r(b+d+1)+r-1) \\
&= (ra+rc,rb+rd+r+r-1) \\
&= (ra+rc,rb+r-1+rd+r-1+1) \\
&= (ra,rb+r-1)+(rb,rd+r-1) \\
&= r\cdot (a,b) + r \cdot (c,d).
\end{align*}

For 7:
\begin{align*}
(r+s)\cdot (a,b) &= ((r+s)a,(r+s)b+(r+s)-1) \\
&= (ra+sa,rb+sb+r+s-1-1+1) \\
&= (ra,rb+r-1)+(sa,sb+s-1) \\
&= r\cdot (a,b) + s\cdot (a,b).
\end{align*}

For 8:
\begin{equation*}
1 \cdot (a,b) = (1\cdot a, 1\cdot b + 1-1) = (a,b).
\end{equation*}

For 9:
\begin{align*}
(rs)\cdot (a,b) &= ((rs)a,(rs)b+(rs)-1) \\
&= (r(sa),r(sb)+rs-r+r-1) \\
&= r \cdot (sa,sb+s-1) \\
&= r \cdot (s \cdot (a,b)).
\end{align*}

For 10:
\begin{align*}
(a,b)+(c,d) &= (a+c,b+d+1) \\
&= (c+a,d+b+1) \\
&= (c,d)+(a,b).
\end{align*}